# Charles - How to rewrite a HTTP response encoded in GZIP?

Tags: http, proxy, url-rewriting, gzip, charles-proxy

I am trying to change the body of a HTTP response (for debugging purposes) using Charles webproxy. However, the response is GZIPed and when I modify something in the body (using the Tools-->Rewrite options) two problems emerge:

1. The `Content-Length` header is not updated to reflect the new data I've added to the response. I have to manually update it myself.
2. Even if I update the `Content-Length` manually, it seems the new GZIP body is invalid (ie, it is not GZIPed correctly).

I can't just remove the `Content-Encoding: gzip` from the ***request*** because I don't have control over the code that consumes the **response**. That code is always expecting a gzip body and it fails to parse the data if I remove the GZIP encoding from the response by removing the `Content-Encoding: gzip` from the request.

How can I modify a GZIPed response body using Charles?

Comment: not a fan of Charles - maybe try a VM and Fiddler instead

Comment: @Tiago did you find the solution?

Comment: @PawełHertman No, I have not found a solution to this unfortunately. :(